# if any instance of my class is clicked hide elem (plain JS)

Tags: javascript

I am trying to simply detect if any instance of my class is clicked; if so, just hide div.

```
var classname = document.getElementsByClassName("big-button");

for (var i = 0; i < classname.length; i++) {
    classname[i].addEventListener('click', myFunction, false);
    document.getElementById('hidethisDiv').style.display = "none";
}
```

Comment: what is `myFunction` ? What is `hidethisDiv` ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to put this code `document.getElementById('hidethisDiv').style.display = "none"` within a function.

```js
var classname = document.getElementsByClassName("big-button");

function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById('hidethisDiv').style.display = "none";
}

for (var i = 0; i < classname.length; i++) {
  classname[i].addEventListener('click', myFunction, false);
}
```

```html
<button class='big-button'>big-button</button>
<div id='hidethisDiv'>Will be hidden soon!</div>
```